# Is it possible to send a UIView by e-mail?

Tags: objective-c, ios, email, uiview, drawing

My application draws on a `UIView`, and I want to send this drawing by e-mail. Is this possible?

Comment: It is, but you have to make it UIImage first

Comment: @Felipe Boszcsowski dude On just Reading The Title of Your Question ,i really got surprise.And in the Description Nice Safe...!! and +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert it into an image and mail that image as an attachment.

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}

-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Check out this image!"];

    // Set up recipients
    // NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"first@example.com"]; 
    // NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com", @"third@example.com", nil]; 
    // NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"]; 

    // [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    // [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];   
    // [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

    // Attach an image to the email
    UIImage *coolImage = ...;
    NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(coolImage);
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"coolImage.png"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"My cool image is attached";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: And one tip : Always do search and research thats what a computer programmer is about, 99% stuffs you will find. More you re/search more you will learn. And after 1 tiring day of search...post here :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this only if you convert it to an image.

**Convert to Image**

You must first link the QuartzCore framework and also `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Next insert in to code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

*source: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/getting-contents-of-uiview-as-uiimage.html*

**Send As Email**

You can use the MFMailComposeViewController class so you don't have to leave your app. This tutorial helped me:

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-discussion/43633-quick-tutorial-how-add-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller.html

To add an image, you can use that same class' method: [addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) that takes in three parameters. Check the apple documents for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading about mailing on some books, and I didn't found informations about Images.

Comment: check these docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html